# Cannot get the newest revision immediately after the file changed on gdrive

Tags: go, caching, google-sheets, google-drive-api, gdrive

From this issue: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client/issues/906

using api v3 to list and sync excel files on gdrive.

```golang
const fieldsContent = "nextPageToken, files(id, name,version, mimeType, size, md5Checksum,modifiedTime,lastModifyingUser,webViewLink)"
const qInParent     = "'%s'  in parents"
const trashFalse    = " and trashed=false"
func (d *Drive) testList(id string)  {
    var driveService *drive.Service
    var pageToken string
    // .....init the service
    fileList, err := driveService.Files.List().Q(fmt.Sprintf(qInParent, id)+trashFalse).
        Fields(fieldsContent).
        PageSize(pageSize).PageToken(pageToken).Do()
    // ... print the files
}
```

Just a simple test case.

At `2021-03-04T15:14:16+08:00`, got test.xlsx state:

Md5Checksum: 668395eb4b0db465efaf631df3aefd86

ModifiedTime: 2021-03-04T07:13:02.100Z

At `2021-03-04T15:16:06+08:00`, got test.xlsx state:

Md5Checksum: 668395eb4b0db465efaf631df3aefd86

ModifiedTime: 2021-03-04T07:13:02.100Z

At `2021-03-04T15:16:28+08:00`, got test.xlsx state:

Md5Checksum: 6155d40b7376d8c675c02ebd5a2394e9

ModifiedTime: 2021-03-04T07:13:48.638Z

The file first change at time: `2021-03-04T07:13:02.100Z`, second change at time:  `2021-03-04T07:13:48.638Z`, but through the api, we can not get the changed file's info immediately, may be delayed a few minutes, perhaps 10 minutes sometime.

Update:
After edit the file on gdrive , download the file through api within several minutes. Still can not get the latest file, still got the previous one.

Comment: About `edit` of `After edit the file on gdrive`, how do you edit it? And you are editing the XLSX file? I couldn't understand about your situation. I apologize for this.

Comment: @TanaikeJust change the content of a cell in the XLSX file, then save it

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. About `Just change the content of a cell in the XLSX file, then save it`, in this case, you open the XLSX file in your Google Drive using your browser and manually edit and save it. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike yes, dead right

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I tested above situation (`you open the XLSX file in your Google Drive using your browser and manually edit and save it.`) and after 3 to 5 seconds,  when I retrieved the revision list and downloaded the latest file from the revision list, the list includes the correct last edited time and the file is the latest file. In the current stage, I cannot replicate your situation. I apologize for this. When I could correctly replicate your situation, I would like to think of the workaround.

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you for replying  too. Sometime could get the newest file immediately, but more often can not get it within 2~3 minutes.You are using python or golang api to retrieve the revision list?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I tested several times. I cannot replicate your situation. I deeply apologize for this. About the method for retrieving the revision list, I used ["Try this API" of Revisions: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/list). By the way, when you want to download the latest file, how about downloading the file using the method of files.get? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads) But I'm not sure whether this is the direction you expect. I apologize.

Comment: @timestee This works fine when you convert to google sheets then? I tried and still could not reproduce it, also I would guess that some propagation is not out of the ordinary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Tanaike i have found the reason.
If you test with Docs Editors file looks like this one :
[image]

i could use api file.get to export the file and download *the latest one*. **but still cannot obtain the VersionNumber and ModifiedTime immediately， still have a delay about several minutes to get the latest VersionNumber and  ModifiedTime**

Please try to test with XLSX file looks like this one, you can not download the latest file and also can not obtain the VersionNumber and ModifiedTime within several minutes after modify and save the file on gdrive.

[image]